# Set default comparison type in Template

Tags: c++

I want to set default class type as default comparison type in Template  and then I want to compares two character strings using templates, I did write code but it’s giving error. Code and error is given below,

```
class CaseSenCmp{
public:
     static int isEqual(char x, char y){        return x==y;    }
};

template<typename c=CaseSenCmp>
int compare(char* str1, char* str2){
  for(int i=0; i<strlen(str1) && i<strlen(str2); i++)
    if(!c::isEqual(str1[i], str2[i]))
        return str1[i]-str2[i];
  return strlen(str1)-strlen(str2); 
}

main(){
char *x = "hello", *y = "HELLO";
compare(x,y);   
}
```

But when i have added this prototype of template, it works

```
template<typename c>
```

Compiler gives this error

```
error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11|
```

Also when i try to do type casting in main function using this code, it also works

```
compare<CaseSenCmp>(x,y);
```

But i want to set Default Policy

Comment: Did you enable C++11 support, like the compiler suggested?

Comment: @MikeSeymour What I find strange is that I've been using default template types long time before c++11 has been established IIRC.

Comment: Thanks dear @MikeSeymour for giving me hint. but i dont know about it, what you have told me. Please let me search it. 
Also can you elaborate it. ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Presumably for class templates, not function templates.

Comment: Default template parameters can be used only in classes until C++11

Comment: @muhammadkhan: Add `-std=c++11` to the compiler's arguments.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Well, that could explain my confusion very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced this issue in code::blocks. To tackle this issue you have to enable

```
-std=c++11
```

into the you compiler. In case of code::blocks you have to follow given below instructions.

Settings->Compiler->Compiler Flags...Look for and check the option to "Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard".  If that doesn't get it then also check the box above it for the C++0x standard.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-std=c++11` to compilation flags, because another way it won't compile.